# Data Scraping, but main content return value none

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, react-table

I am able to login properly, keep the session and browse other pages but after doing `print(driver.get(full_path))` the return value shows `None`. I don't understand why it's showing `None`. But when I run the script I can see the pages being browsed.

Even though I've tried other ways to get data, the same results are showing all the time, like `None`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
import pathlib,pickle
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

# Github credentials
email = ""
password = ""

# initialize the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("")


login_path = "https://finbox.com/login/email"

def save_cookies_file():
    driver.get(login_path)
    
    # login info
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'email').send_keys(email)
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password').send_keys(password)
    
    # submit button
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, '_105e3d41').click()
    
    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))
    time.sleep(10)

save_cookies_file();



""" cokies detials """
def search(text):    
    cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
    for cookie in cookies:
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)
    
    bank_path = f"https://finbox.com/DSE:{text}"
    full_path = bank_path + "/financials/income_statement"
    
    print(driver.get(full_path)) // problem is here

    time.sleep(10)
    
    # print("Main content:", driver_data)
    
    
    # table = driver_data.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "rt-tbody")
    # table = driver_data.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "rt-tbody")
    # table = driver_data.find(By.CLASS_NAME, "rt-tbody")
    # table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]')
    # print("table len : ", len(table))
    # print("table type: ", type(table))
    # print("table content: ", table)

search("ABBANK")
```

Answer (score 1):

`driver.get()` returns `None`. Always. It navigates to the specified URL but cannot be expected to return any value, as you've tried.